# Python errors in command prompt

Tags: python

I have a python script that use tasks to write to excel files.

The script runs fine nor problems at all but I have a lot of warnings when I run.

The questions are:

1.-That errors are from the PIP install applications or from the script?

2.-I need to update something in the python or the PIP?

I want to check because clearly it says in future will affect but I don't know if this is due the code development or installation files in my computer.

Thank you

These are the type of errors I receive:

```
C:\asg\conversor\main.py:101: FutureWarning: As the xlwt package is no longer maintained, the xlwt engine will be removed in a future version of pandas. This is the only engine in pandas that supports writing in the xls format. Install openpyxl and write to an xlsx file instead. You can set the option io.excel.xls.writer to 'xlwt' to silence this warning. While this option is deprecated and will also raise a warning, it can be globally set and the warning suppressed.
  df.to_excel(dst[:-1], index=False, header=None)
sys:1: FutureWarning: In a future version of pandas all arguments of read_csv except for the argument 'filepath_or_buffer' will be keyword-only.
C:\asg\conversor\main.py:101: FutureWarning: As the xlwt package is no longer maintained, the xlwt engine will be removed in a future version of pandas. This is the only engine in pandas that supports writing in the xls format. Install openpyxl and write to an xlsx file instead. You can set the option io.excel.xls.writer to 'xlwt' to silence this warning. While this option is deprecated and will also raise a warning, it can be globally set and the warning suppressed.
  df.to_excel(dst[:-1], index=False, header=None)
sys:1: FutureWarning: In a future version of pandas all arguments of read_csv except for the argument 'filepath_or_buffer' will be keyword-only.
C:\asg\conversor\main.py:101: FutureWarning: As the xlwt package is no longer maintained, the xlwt engine will be removed in a future version of pandas. This is the only engine in pandas that supports writing in the xls format. Install openpyxl and write to an xlsx file instead. You can set the option io.excel.xls.writer to 'xlwt' to silence this warning. While this option is deprecated and will also raise a warning, it can be globally set and the warning suppressed.
  df.to_excel(dst[:-1], index=False, header=None)
sys:1: FutureWarning: In a future version of pandas all arguments of read_csv except for the argument 'filepath_or_buffer' will be keyword-only.
C:\asg\conversor\main.py:101: FutureWarning: As the xlwt package is no longer maintained, the xlwt engine will be removed in a future version of pandas. This is the only engine in pandas that supports writing in the xls format. Install openpyxl and write to an xlsx file instead. You can set the option io.excel.xls.writer to 'xlwt' to silence this warning. While this option is deprecated and will also raise a warning, it can be globally set and the warning suppressed.
  df.to_excel(dst[:-1], index=False, header=None)
```

Comment: That's a warning, not an error. And it seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: These warnings seem pretty clear. Your code is using features that will be removed and you are getting warnings to fix those problems. Is this code you control? If others control it, what are their plans for updates?

Comment: Please do not add arbitrary tags to your question. Regarding the question itself: the warning seems pretty straightforward indeed. Did you read it and follow up the advice? If so, what are the problems you encountered?

Comment: df.to_excel is causing problems an alternative is to save it as csv. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xlwt engine` is used by `pandas` for writing `xls` files. As warning are saying that in near future this will be removed from `pandas` lib and `pandas` will no longer be able to write `xls` files. They are telling you to use newer `xlsx` files. And for that you'll need `openpyxl` if you don't have it already.

For reading difference between `xls` and `xlsx` files: [read this](https://www.minitool.com/news/xls-vs-xlsx.html)

For `openpyxl`: [read this](https://www.javatpoint.com/python-openpyxl)